# Step-By-Step rendering in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to locate a step-by-step overview of Unity's rendering process, from the start all the way to the correct pixels on the screen lighting up.

No amount of searching has located a description of the kind (maybe I'm just bad).

Anyone know and willing to type out the nitty-gritty of it, or point me at a source I'm missing?

To clarify and avoid x-y-problems, I have been asked to 'analyze the way Unity's graphics engine works, mentioning the entire background procedure and the technologies used'.

Comment: exect [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) that you might have already see, I do not know any doc of this kind

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptableRenderPipeline.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Rendering-Tech.html, Don't excatly know what you want but there are some pages in Unity docs that are hard to find with google, so i advise you to search the unity manual too manually

Comment: Have you tried the Frame Debugger?

Comment: Handy links, all 3, but they don't quite hit home. Formally, I've been asked to 'Analyze the way Unity's graphics engine works, mentioning the entire background procedure and the technologies used'. And honestly, I don't entirely understand the question's intended answer.

Comment: Also there is a guy named "Ruzihm" here who is on the spot when it comes to graphics & Unity, he might will also help you

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses different renderers depeding on your selected use-case.
Namely:

- [Universal Render Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/index.html)
- [High Definition Render Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.1/manual/Getting-started-with-HDRP.html)

  You can find detailed documentations there(pictures and graphs about rendering loops etc), however Unity is not open source unlike UE(altought the scriptable render pipeline is for filling this gap afaik at least graphics wise) so you might not gonna get really in depth knowledge like you imagine.

Also i highly recommend searching for articles throught the [Unity blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/) because quite often Unity engineers write articles there, and reveal some under the hood things :)

Speaking about blog posts like this:

- [Siggraph 2019](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/09/03/watch-the-unity-graphics-sessions-from-siggraph-2019/) (SIGGRAPH is the world’s largest conference for
  computer graphics technology and research, so this might be usefull
  for you)
- [SRP](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/02/28/srp-batcher-speed-up-your-rendering/) (Sriptebale Render Pipeline) I think in this article they also talked about some under the hood things but i don't remember actually